# Need Build IVR call flow UI with Drag-Drop element like OpenVBX (Twilio)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ivr

Need to create application for desing IVR call flow with drag-drop element UI like **OpenVBX(Twilio)**. I have no advance level knowledge about front-end technologies like **CSS and pure JavaScript**. I need to this implementation with PHP based project.

Can you please help me out which kind of tool are helpful for this requirement?

Comment: What do you mean a tool? Like a text editor? Or a library? What have you tried so far and what specifically are you looking for help with?

Comment: I need **php based library or Drag-Drop editor** that can be easily ingrate with our project.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions are not opensource and free.

We use the OpenSource/GPL HawHaw (from the HawHaw.de), if you are using the standard VoiceXML language. You can create a portal that will be accessible from the Web / "Wap" / VoiceXML. You can test it on the HTML interface (and ajust your Session/DB/API integration) and play it from the VoiceXML syntax (you need a VoiceXML interpreter as Voximal, Plum, Voxeo...)

Comment: Is there any open source library available?

Comment: You have some old VoiceXML/PHP opensource classes. But I don't think that they solve your request. Perhaps you can plan to shift to a voice portal created with AI/Chatbot. Voximal for example allows to replace the VoiceXML/CallFlow with a natural language interaction. The tools and the method are very different.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use D3 js library for drag and drop interface and then integrate with your VOIP platform.